# Invoke-Expression to Launch .ps1 scripts

Tags: powershell

I am trying to make a service that scans a folder. When it detects certain files it renames them and then creates variables for the rest of the script. This all works fine, but I am trying to find a way to run this script so that the subsequent windows that it launches are minimized. I've tried the below, but the 2 scripts still launch a window each that flashes on the screen.

I have tried converting the file into an EXE and a service but then it refuses to work. Hoping for a quick one-liner if anyone can help?

```
Set-Location -Path C:\scripts\ICVT

while ($true) {
invoke-expression 'cmd /c start powershell -WindowStyle Minimized -Command {.\file_checker.ps1}';
Start-Sleep 5
invoke-expression 'cmd /c start powershell -WindowStyle Minimized -Command {.\kill_checker.ps1}';
Start-Sleep 5
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use `Invoke-Expression`? Doing it how you have it will always launch a window. If you instead run the PowerShell script in the session with the dot sourcing it (dot space script.ps1) i.e.:
`. .\file_checker.ps1` you won't launch any new windows.

Comment: Or even the invoke *operator* `&`

Comment: The reason I want to launch a new PS window is that I have 2 different scripts that need to run constantly, and when they detect certain files they need to rename the files, get-content as variables, and then execute the script with those variables. If I allow single windows to run continuously then the scanning operation stops while the script runs, which means that the new files that are coming in go unprocessed, causing delays. I want to be able to execute new instances of the scripts each time files are detected and this is the only way I've found so far that almost works.

Comment: `Start-Process powershell -WindowStyle Minimized -ArgumentList @('-command', '"c:\path\to\file_checker.ps1"')` will probably do it.

Comment: Works great, thanks @TessellatingHeckler

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to use [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job) to run the script in the background. Simply replace the `Invoke-Expression` with `Start-Job`:

```
Set-Location -Path C:\scripts\ICVT

while ($true) {
Start-Job -FilePath '.\file_checker.ps1}';
Start-Sleep 5
Start-Job -FilePath '.\kill_checker.ps1}';
Start-Sleep 5
}
```

It will also accept script blocks as well. See [about_jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_jobs) for more information on running and managing background jobs.

Comment: For some reason the jobs don't seem to execute my scripts properly, although they do run. Must be something inherently wrong with the way I have written my scripts. Thanks for the help @HAL9256